# Angular Difference ViewChild vs ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, viewchild, controlvalueaccessor

What's the difference between ViewChild and ControlValueAccessor in Angular? Seems both of them can access child components, directives, DOM. So curious about the differences in usage, can one do something the other cannot do?

Comment: Not sure about the exact difference but `ControlValueAccessor` used for form API related stuff and `ViewChild` in general accessing any DOM element

Comment: ControlValueAccesor is to make a custom form control, that's a "special control" to control a variable using [(ngModel)] or a FormControl. e.g. a gauge, a datePiker, etc. ViewChild is to get an element inside a component. There are not any similitude

Comment: hi @Eliseo feel free to place in answer and I can send points, just for background information, I have teammate using ControlValueAccessor to access a Child FormBuilder Component  Address (with multiple fields, city, state, zip, etc), the question was whether to use ViewChild or ControlValueaccessor to access this formbuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ControlValueAccesor is for making a **custom form control**.

By steps, a FormControl can store anything, even an object. Imagine two different FormGroups

```
form1=new FormGroup({
   name:new FormControl('name')
   direcction:new FormControl({address:'address',cp:'cp'})
})

form2=new FormGroup({
   name:new FormControl('name')
   direction:new FormGroup({
       address:new FormControl('address'),
       cp:new FormControl('cp')
   })
```

both have the same "value"

```
{name:'name',direction:{address:'adress',cp:'cp'}}
```

While using a form array, you can have

```
form1=new FormGroup({
   name:new FormControl('name')
   direcction:new FormArray([
      new FormControl({address:'address1',cp:'cp1'}),
      new FormControl({address:'address2',cp:'cp2'})
     ]
})

form2=new FormGroup({
   name:new FormControl('name')
   direction:new FormArray([
      FormGroup({
        address:new FormControl('address1'),
        cp:new FormControl('cp1')
      }),
      FormGroup({
        address:new FormControl('address2'),
        cp:new FormControl('cp2')
      })]
  })
```

And again, both give the same "value"

```
{
  name:'name',direction:[
     {address:'address1',cp:'cp1'},
     {address:'address2',cp:'cp2'}]
}
```

You can make a custom form control to control a FormControl that stores an object, and the use ControlValueAccessor, but really I prefer another approach(*); that it's make a simple component and pass as input the formGroup or the formControl. If you want to maintenance the things simplest not use a formControl to store an object. If I have a component app-direction like

```
@Input()formGroup

<input [formControl]="formGroup('address')">
<input [formControl]="formGroup('cp')">
```

You can use as

```
<app-direction [formGroup]="myform.get('direcction')"></app-direction>
```

or if you have a Form Array

```
<div *ngFor="let group of myForm.get('direction').controls">
 <app-direction [formGroup]="group"></app-direction>
</div>
```

No ViewChild, no ControlValueAccesor, no nothing, and the form is created in the main.component.

Well, your teammate is using a ControlValueAccesor to control an object? It's only an opinion, but he is complicating the application, really: "makes things simple", see how others resolve similar problems, re-inventing the wheel usually is a bad idea

(*)In my opinion a custom form control should be used to make a "special control" with a "special appearance"

Comment: hi @Eliseo  do you happen to know answer to this question also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315005/angular-using-viewchild-and-input-at-the-same-time-side-effects-or-best-practi

Answer (score 0):

`ViewChild` is used to to get access to a child component, directive or a DOM element from a parent component class, e.g. if you want to access the native DOM properties of a child element then you may use `ViewChild` to get access to the element and access it element.nativeElement [example](https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/).

`ControlValueAccessor` acts as a bridge between the Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM. You will use this when you want to create a custom form element and want that element to be part of Angular forms API, so that the validation and other things work. e.g. You may want to create a auto-complete control and want it to be part of form group, then you will implement `ControlValueAccessor`, [example](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/).

Comment: I can also access the child component variables and child Forms with Viewchild, very interesting not only DOM

Comment: yes, that's what I mentioned "to get access to a child component, directive or a DOM element"