# Custom component FormControl take error when added new array element to form

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components

Maybe someone help me. I display the component in the form, to child component  i transfer formGroup objects from formArray.

But when I add a new object to formArray I get an error "**ERROR Error: control.registerOnChange is not a function**", but everything works.

I created stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fceyyq
Maybe someone will tell me what could be the problem, maybe the approach is not right?

If i created component without ControlValueAccessor and transfer to the component object with formGroup  then there are no more errors.
But I’m not sure what is so right because we are managing a parent object from a child component.

Comment: you has `let control of addressArray`, as you has a FromArray of FormGroups,  control is a FormGroup, a custom form control is for FormControls, not for FormGroups . Take a look to the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163266/angular-difference-viewchild-vs-controlvalueaccessor/60164588#60164588

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-container` instead of `div` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57141934/794242) as use of `*ngFor` creates an implicit template.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let control of form.get('address'); let i = index">
   <app-address [formControl]="control"></app-address>
</ng-container>
```